# Circuit simulator tool for OS X?

Tags: macos, applications, software-recommendation

Anyone know any circuit simulator tool for OS X like Simulink or Proteus?

Comment: Please be more specifik?

Answer (score 1):

I've been using EAGLE some time ago. http://www.cadsoftusa.com/eagle-pcb-design-software/?language=en

Comment: AFAIK, EAGLE can't actually simulate circuits

Answer (score 0):

Have you ever considered [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com)? It's web-based, and sufficient for most uses.

One short [Google query](https://www.google.com/search?q=circuit%20simulator%20mac) later: [iCircuit](http://icircuitapp.com)